# In KOTH mode, does the counter increase faster when there are more people of the owning team on the point?

Tags: overwatch

I know that, in payload mode, the payload moves faster when there are up to 3 people next to it. 
But I haven't been able to figure out if the percent counter increases  faster when there are more people on the point in KOTH.

I often see players wandering ahead to prevent the other team to even enter the main area and find myself alone on the point.
So I was wondering, once the point is captured, do we need to have any people at all on the point to increase the counter (except of course, when it is contested and you have to defend it) ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**No.**

The number of people on the point matters when capturing it (capped at 3 people for maximum cap speed), but once you own the point, the percentage meter fills up at a static rate regardless of team presence.

I have video proof that I can't upload currently. Before I do, I'll probably edit them together to give a side by side view.

Comment: I don't remember the exact time it takes to capture, do you remember it? I searched but with "KOTH" in my sentence I found 2 entire page of people posting and reposting again "KOTH bugged for ranked" .
I know it's either 30 second alone either it's 45 (then 45-30-15 or 30-20-10) but I can't remember.

Comment: I'll do some solo testing tonight and provide gif or video footage of both time-to-capture with 1/2 players and time-to-100 with 0/1/2 players for the second.

Comment: I think it might be interesting to test if for capture, KOTH, and capture-before-payload it is the same time (for 1 people). I'll do the test once back from work but I won't capture them. I'll give my result (and also i'll try for multiple map), but if you want to capture it..

Comment: From experience, KOTH capture time is much faster. I'll also run the test, but I don't think capturing is necessarily worth it unless I keep it in video format, rather than converting to more shareable .gifs

Comment: Yes thanks, I don't think it's useful to capture but since you said you wanted to share a gif I wanted to warn I won't.

Comment: Videos are uploading right now, but both standing on point and running around set the match over in a little over 2 minutes. So there is indeed no impact standing on the point if you already control it.

Comment: Thanks for all your efforts, I think Blizzard needs to make these rules more explicit. Do you think there is an explicit will from them to let the players discovers these gameplay mechanics by themselves ?

Comment: So my video's couldn't upload- it tanked my connection and failed. But I can definitely confirm that standing on the point versus running around like a lunatic makes no difference in terms of percentage completion.

Comment: Ok thanks for taking the time to try :-). I'll mark your answer as accepted so.

Comment: @kerwan Thanks! Also, regarding your earlier comment, I'd like to think they do want players to discover this by themselves. It makes things that much more fun to SCIENCE!! it all :)

Comment: @KizTrap Yep, I think that all the speculations about both the lore and the gameplay mechanics really add a nice feeling to game.

Answer (score 3):

From my oberservation i can say that you don´t have to stay on the point after you captured it.

I had a round in Illios where we captured the point and drove our Enemies back to their spawnpoint and won the round without any of us on it.

Comment: Ah good to know, I guess I have been playing it kind of wrong by always standing on the point.